# How to convert a netlist to circuit diagram?

Tags: simulation, linux, ngspice

I was working on both verilog and ngspice.  I found out a verilog can be converted into VLSI CSD design with microwind or qflow. My question is, Is it possible to convert an ngspice netlist to schematic anyhow?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. If you're asking us to recommend existing software that does this, that would be off-topic. What is your specific question?

Comment: is there any software that can do that?

Comment: Well, in a quick search, I found [NetlistViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/netlistviewer/), but the reviews indicate that its functionality is rather limited, and it hasn't been maintained for the last ~1.5 years. It is a **hard** problem. Even the commercial tools I've seen struggle to produce a useful diagram. It might be interesting to see what could be done with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), using its "ortho" layout engine and a bunch of custom symbols, but even that has its limitations.

Answer (score 3):

A schematic shows how components are connected in a "human readable" form.

A netlist also shows how components are connected but in a "computer readable" form.

So actually they basically contain the same information.

So in principle it is **always** possible to convert a netlist into a schematic. If not by software then a human can do this.

If the tools you use can do this is a question you can answer by reading the tool's manual or asking the vendor's support desk.